# How to create a link that goes to specific page, waits 3 seconds, then auto clicks on internal link on current page?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make a link where after it is clicked it brings you to a specific page, waits 3 seconds, then automatically clicks on a specific internal link on that current page?

Currently I have this

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com#pupup_element_27_child">Go to Page</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 if(window.location.hash === "#pupup_element_27_child"){

 }
```

I have checked several other questions that I thought may be similar but nothing as specific as this.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without code on the new page. Once you go to the new page, the current page's JavaScript stops running.

Comment: What code? I have access as this is all happening on the same website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` to delay the action by 3 seconds after the new page is loaded.

```
if (window.location.hash === "#pupup_element_27_child") {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("#pupup_element_27_child").click();
  }, 3000);
}
```

This JavaScript goes on the target page.

Answer (score 2):

If there are two different pages, you could use an URL param to follow the desired link after 3s. Code in the target page (add ?followLink after the URL):

```html
<body onload="followLink()">
<a href="http://pudim.com.br" id="link" target="_blank">Automatically follow this link after 3s</a>
<script>
  function followLink(){
  var params = window.location.search;
  if (params.indexOf("followLink")){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('#link').click();
              },3000);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think it's the same page, it's a new page in the same site.

Comment: @Barmar you're probably right. I edited my answer to consider two different pages in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another page (on your website) and redirect to another page on the same website, the intermediate page must necessarily have a script that waits for the desired time and redirects.

If you don't want to do this everytime you access to that middle page, you can pass some query params and configure your method to wait only if some query params are present

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, when user clicks a link on your current page, it's gonna lead to another page where you want to automatically click a link that exists in that page, then in your current page, put this script. You can set the time to whatever you like. Hope that answers your question.

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<a href="anotherLink.html" id="openThis">Go to Page</a>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
 document.querySelector("#openThis").click();
  }, 2000);
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the location test logic, set a Timeout that will take your internal link and then click on it. You should consider jQuery.

```
if(window.location.hash === "#pupup_element_27_child"){
    #Add a timeout here
    setTimeout(()=>{
        #Load the target url with whatever API/Library desired
        window.location.href="https://my_new_location";
    },3000);
}
```